# How do I run a Cat command in a Linux Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am getting a syntax error if I run the shell script using `nohup`, where I have added a `cat` command in it.

In the script (InboxOnetimeDoneCorrectedWithMerge.sh) I have added this line:

```
cat $Files/"AML_BM_"$date".TXT" <(tail --lines=+2 $Files/"BRANCHMOG.txt") > $Files/"AML_BM_PLUS_BRANCHMOG_"$date".TXT"
```

If I run the script InboxOnetimeDoneCorrectedWithMerge.sh using

```
nohup ./InboxOnetimeDoneCorrectedWithMerge.sh >log.txt &
```

then I get the below error:

```
./InboxOnetimeDoneCorrectedWithMerge.sh: line 88: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./InboxOnetimeDoneCorrectedWithMerge.sh: line 88: `cat $Files/"AML_BM_"$date".TXT" <(tail --lines=+2 $Files/"BRANCHMOG.txt") > $Files/"AML_BM_PLUS_BRANCHMOG_"$date".TXT"'
```

If I just simply run the script using

```
./InboxOnetimeDoneCorrectedWithMerge.sh
```

then it gets executed properly.

Why it is throwing syntax error on running it in background ?

Comment: You don't specify whether your script has a shebang on the front, but when `nohup scriptname` and `./scriptname` differ, that _often_ implies you're relying on fallback behavior. Always use a shebang when you want consistent behavior -- because your script uses bash-only syntax, that shebang should be something like `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. (Also, putting a `.sh` extension on a _bash_ script is often a bad idea; it implies folks can run `sh yourscript`, but that's not true: `sh` is a different shell and doesn't support `bash`-only features)

Comment: (...on the `.sh` extension topic, see also the essay [Commandname extensions considered harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/))

Comment: its #! /bin/bash
What is the solution for this ?

Comment: I'm not able to produce that problem from your code without using `sh`. That said, the code _does_ have other issues -- consider running it through http://shellcheck.net.

Comment: Out of curiosity -- while this certainly isn't good long-term practice -- does specifying an interpreter, as in `nohup bash ./InboxOnetimeDoneCorrectedWithMerge.sh >log.txt 2>&1 &` behave any differently?

Comment: BTW, `nohup` doesn't do much that's very useful; you can get the effect of running something in the background without exiting when the terminal dies without it. `./InboxOnetimeDoneCorrectedWithMerge.sh >log.txt 2>&1 </dev/null & disown -h "$!"` for example gives you all the useful effects without actually needing the `nohup` executable at all.

Comment: ...that said: insofar as this is a _very_ common problem and the solution is pretty  much always "ensure that bash is used instead of sh", a [mre] is really called for so folks can see the problem themselves in enough detail to work out _why_ the shebang you're using doesn't address the issue. Think about trying to reproduce it in an online sandbox like https://repl.it/; that would take any local-environment-specific weirdness out of the picture (or at least replace it with weirdness that's available for inspection/investigation, vs weirdness happening on a host only you can access).